# What algorithm to compare string against multiple patterns?

Tags: algorithms, string-matching

My problem can be characterized as a string-search problem for a finite amount of patterns. So Aho-Corasick algorithm would be a good first choice.

However, I have certain properties that limit the scope of the problem, and I was wondering if there was another, better suited algorithm.

- A set of known strings to search for (less than a thousand patterns).
- The patterns are short (less than 20 characters).
- The patterns are quite disjunct, in a way that most of them don't share a common prefix.
- A large number of strings to search in (millions).
- The strings which are searched for the patterns are short too.
- Any hit would be an exact match.
- I want to stop searching after the first hit has been found.

Comment: What is the problem with Aho-Corasick? Your problem can be solved with it in linear time. Are you looking for some optimizations in runtime or a simpler algorithm?

Comment: One assumption I can make is that there will only be exact matches. I only check weather a given input is (exactly) one of a known set of patterns. Aho-Corasick will work in this case, but I was specifically interested in an algorithm that might be more suited to this task.

Comment: I think in that case trie or hashing would be the right way to go.